# log4j - stdout vs fileout?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, stdout

What is the difference between stdout and fileout in log4j?

If I have this set in my log4j.properties file,

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, fileout
....
log4j.logger.org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy=INFO, stdout, fileout
```

Is it necessary to set these to all 3 of the above options (INFO, stdout, fileout)? Will this cause duplicate lines to appear? If I remove "fileout" will I be losing any potentially important print statements from the log file?

Comment: These are artibrary identifiers of appenders: `stdout` is defined using the `log4j.appender.stdout` prefix, `fileout` is defined using the `log4j.appender.fileout`. What they actually are depends on the rest of your configuration. BTW:  Log4j 1.x has reached end-of-life 8 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

The output destinations for writing log events in Log4j are **stdout** and **fileout**.

1. **stdout** is used for the standard output stream, which is usually the console or terminal window where you run the program.
2. **fileout** is used Log events are written to a file on a disc via a file output stream. The Log4j configuration file allows for the specification of the file's name and location.

Comment: By a disc do you mean like a flashdrive? So stdout is completely different from fileout in that stdout is just some print statements but fileout was text that was actually written to a disc/flash drive?